# iOS - Parsing nested .plist Dictionaries with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, tableview, plist

I'm having a lot of difficulty parsing a ".plist" with nested Dictionaries to use as the backend for a TableView. I am trying to use "Category" as the Table Section Header, "Items" displayed as the row(s) in the table and the "url" as the value of the row. I can't seem to figure this out. Am I going about this the wrong way? Any help/advice would be much appreciated.

Here's the .plist as XML

==============

I need 10 "reputation" points to to post a picture... God.. Love this site and hate it at the same time... THis site gives me as many headaches as the bugs I try and fix... @Stack... Your NLP needs work.

Endless

```
Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.
You need at least 10 reputation to post more than 2 links.
```

I have formatted and reformatted XML... I know it's correct... Why do I even bother with this site? Sorry...

=============

Here's my .swift

```
var data = [String:[[String:String]]] ()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("MyPlistFile", ofType: "plist"), plistData = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as? [String:[[String:String]]] {

        for (category, titleAndUrl) in plistData {
            for urls in titleAndUrl {
                let urlA = urls["Category A"]
                let urlB = urls["Category B"]
                data.append(urlA!)
                data.append(urlB!)
            }
        }
    }


func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return ???.count
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return ???.count

}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return Category[section]
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(sectionsTableIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell


    return cell
}
```

Comment: Just add a url to the image and I will insert it

Comment: Try not putting so much in a single statement. Intermediate statements help a lot for debugging and comprehension.

Comment: Just put the image URL in a comment

Comment: The XML is in a separate statement (I think). I need to take a class on StackOverflow ;>

Comment: Guess what, complaining about SO at the same time you are asking for help is not good form or beneficial.

Comment: Without seeing your Plist structure I can't give a precise answer, but I can tell you that you aren't using the enumerated values in your loops (`category` in the case of the outer loop`) and that you should probably create an array of Strings to hold your categories and dictionary of arrays for your items - UITableViews work much better with arrays

Comment: @zaph - Guess what... it's called "boiling over". Thanks for your advice